# How To Enable Php Mcrypt on Mac Os X Lion 10.7.4

Tags: php, macos, osx-lion, mcrypt

I have been trying to enable mcrypt for two days in OS X. I read lots of document but I could not accomplish. Maybe it is because I am new in OS X environment.

The brief summary what I have done so far is;

I installed Xcode and installed Command Line Tools.

Downloaded and extracted libmcrypt-2.5.8 and php-5.3.15.

```
cd libmcrypt-2.5.8
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

The output of this is

```
Libraries have been installed in:
/usr/local/lib
```

and some other logs like

```
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
```

The next step is;

```
cd php-5.3.15/ext/mcrypt
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

The output of this is

```
Installing shared extensions:
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
```

According to documents that I read, this means the installation is successful. After all these I opened `/etc/php.ini` and wrote `extension=mcrypt.so`. I restarted apache with sudo apachectl restart. But nothing happened. Mcrypt did not appear in `php -m`.

I also tried to install mcrypt with sudo port install `php-mcrypt +universal` but also this did not worked.

I saw another topic which is related to this problem and there was an answer which says that changing `extension=mcrypt.so` with full path of `mcrypt.so`. I tried and that is also not worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found this walkthrough useful, http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server/

Comment: thanks. that tutorial worked for me, except it gives me an error "error: 'PHP_FE_END' undeclared here" at first.. Found another strange solution, had to edit ext/mcrypt/mcrypt.c, replace PHP_FE_END with {NULL,NULL,NULL}. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 'extension_dir' property is set in your php.ini or if its already there check that its not commented.

Comment: I also tried it but it did not work either. Above of extension=mcrypt.so i wrote extension_dir (not commented) and its path was the folder which has mcrypt.so. I again restarted apache but it did not worked.