# Laravel - artisan command not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am getting started with using laravel on Mac and am using MAMP. I am using the `artisan' command with laravel in php.

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --table=users --create
```

But it is giving me this error

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --table=users --create
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension.
```

I have installed the mcrypt extension for PHP.

```
brew install php53-mcrypt
```

This gives me a message saying that it is already installed: `php53-mcrypt-5.3.26 already installed`

Comment: How did you install it, what OS?

Comment: Im using mac osx and installed it using brew install php53-mcrypt

Comment: Are you using MAMP or similar? Maybe you have 2 different versions of PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP being different when run in the command line versus through your web server turns out to be a [pretty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019330/how-to-enable-php-mcrypt-on-mac-os-x-lion-10-7-4/12025602#12025602) [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension/16837198#16837198) [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694866/laravel-lacking-mcrypt-extension-only-when-using-phpunit) (note that those are three separate links with possible solutions :D)

The key point is to:

1. make sure the correct PHP binary (the one used by MAMP) is in your PATH
2. (less likely) to check to see if your CLI-run php.ini and loaded extensions is different from your web-server (apache)-run PHP (They can be potentially different).

Finally, please consider saving your time and some stress by using [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) or another [VM provider](https://www.virtualbox.org/), which gives you the ability to run a "real" web server on your computer without mucking up your Mac OS install!

Comment: Going along with your point #1, `php --ri bcrypt` should let you know if it's installed.