# Laravel - Artisan not working

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-4

I'm aware of the other questions [out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910502/laravel-artisan-command-not-working), but they are different to my situation.

I installed a fresh copy of my own laravel, and I tried running `php artisan list`, which works.

Now, I have a colleague who has installed a copy of laravel himself, and he pushes his entire directory onto a git repository. I pulled the entire branch off the repository, and tried running `php artisan list`, but nothing happens this time. I mean, literally, nothing happens.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Have you run `composer install` after cloning the repo? That said, I wouldn't expect **nothing** to happen if the error was as bad as being unable to load in files (though it could depend on your display_error settings).

Comment: UNIX/Windows/OSX? Are you pushing `composer.phar` too?

Comment: @Sergiu I'm using OSX.

Comment: @Alexrussell I'm supposed to run composer install? Sorry I'm new to working with laravel/command line in php

Comment: seems to work now after i run composer install. Is there any particular reason why?

Comment: Yes. `composer install` downloads the dependencies you defined in `composer.json` in your `vendor` folder that you do not push to git. Artisan is part of the `laravel` package that's a dependency.

Comment: thanks. If you can add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks @HeHui, I've added the answer below. As Dennis already got in with my answer after you said it was the reason I figured I'd give a little more info in my answer in order to still make it a better choice for acceptance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Generally speaking, the `vendor` directory is not committed to VCS, as such, doing a clone on a standard Laravel app won't include all its dependencies.

Once you have cloned, doing `composer install` (or `composer update` if you want the latest packages as a developer) will fetch the dependencies and allow your app to work.

Answer (score 12):

You need to run `composer install`, so the composer refresh all dependencies, artisan's begin on the middle. That should do the job!

Comment: Good Job, you made my day.

Comment: Glad I could be at help! :D

Answer (score 7):

My artisan was not working because i had the following lines in my routes.php

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['c_id'])) {
    header("Location: /login_page.php");
    exit();
}
```

I simply commented the exit(). So my code becomes as follows

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['c_id'])) {
    header("Location: /login_page.php");
//    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to point out some thing to anyone struggling with artisan, as this answer is 1st link in google to artisan CLI empty line:

It will print blank line whenever some error happens, even if you have all dependencies installed with `composer install`. And it won't tell you exactly what is wrong. I couldn't figure it out until I put into artisan file in the root directory this:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

That forced artisan CLI to show error message and therefore I was able to fix it (my .env file was broken).

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Environment file is not usually pushed to repo.

Make sure you'd also put ".env" file at root path.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was to connect artisan with database (migrates) i.e. the command

```
$php artisan migrate
```

was not working.

I was running laravel project on 8888 port.
In this case I updated .env file as:
DB_HOST=localhost to DB_HOST=localhost to `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`
and DB_PORT=3306 to `DB_PORT=8889`

Cleared cache by running artisan command and run the migrates:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score -3):

delete the your php at your system , and install it again
or if you run the app, move project folder at `htdocs` in 
xampp folder and type address in browser , `localhost/your project name` and your app is run on localhost

Comment: this answer has no relevance to my question asked