# Laravel 5.0 - Shared Hosting - Artisan not working as it should

Tags: php, laravel-5, cpanel

I actually wanted to follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882897/laravel-artisan-not-working#), but I guess It's better to start a new question.

I installed a fresh copy of my own laravel(5.0), and I tried running php artisan route:list, which works.

Now I have downloaded the compressed repository of a project I want to deploy on a shared hosting enviorment, but when I run php artisan route:list nothing happens.(No error message, nothing). Using [this method](http://blog.hawkhost.com/2013/09/24/installing-laravel-at-hawk-host/) for hosting the application

The actual problem is `php artisan migrate`, which also outputs nothing!

Is there a good method for troubleshooting this ?
Could you provide me we some points of failure that I can check ?

Worth mentioning:
I'm no Laravel developer and I have limited time reading up on it.

Comment: Do you get any error? Imo, the Laravel's dependencies are probably not included in your package. Try to perform a `composer update` to force the dependencies to be fetched from the repository.

Comment: try giving `storage` folder a write permission with `sudo chmod -R 755 storage/` if that dont work try `777`

Comment: The application produces no code: http://laravel.cloud03.attend.no/
Hence no errors, APP_DEBUG=true

Tried updating composer, and changing mod on storage, no difference.

Comment: artisan it's a php script. You can open and see his content. A correct version of artisan file, it must to be write any on console after execute. Ok message or error messages. If not meesages, you can force messages put ant top of ile after <?php this lines-> ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors",true);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As LittleFinger suggested, it's possible that artisan is not actually yet installed. When deploying from a repo, Laravel's packages of which the entire framework core is composed, are not included. You should run composer install to install the packages. If you don't have composer installed that can be difficult on shared hosting, but it's usually possible to install it.

You will need to run composer install before you run composer update. Running composer update is not required, unless you want to update to the newest versions of your packages which are allowed by the rules in your composer.json file. This should be done with care in a production environment as new versions of packages could break your app.

Once you've installed the packages, you'll need to set your environment variables (database credentials etc.) by copying the .env.example file to .env and editing it. Once you've done this you'll be able to run php artisan key:generate to generate an encryption key.

After this, your app should work (assuming you've pointed a domain to the /public directory).

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue when I try to run 
`php artisan migrate or php artisan cache:clear` 
nothing happen just a blank screen no success no error see the screenshot
[image: php artisan command]

after debugging I found a message in error_log in root directory which says.

> Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size

after increasing the memory `php artisan commands` works fine
[image: commands run successfully]